# React functional component: Trying to set a state once a window break point is reached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Here is my code for the problem, my issue is that the event is triggering multiple times when it hits the 960px breakpoint. This should only fire once it reaches the breakpoint, but I am getting an almost exponential amount of event triggers.

````js
 const mediaQuery = '(max-width: 960px)';
 const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery);
 mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
   if (event.matches) {
     setState((prevState) => ({
       ...prevState,
       desktopNavActivated: false,
     }));
   } else {
     setState((prevState) => ({
       ...prevState,
       menuActivated: false,
       navItemExpanded: false,
     }));
   }
 });```
````

Comment: addEventListener is a side effect, you can't run them in render. use useEffect for that

Comment: incase you changed your component to function component which i think will be more effective you can check this codepen to do it :https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-breeze-8ty87?file=/src/useWidth.js:520-531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow!

1. I'm going to assume, that your code does not run within a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, which will result in a new event listener being added to your `mediaQueryList` *every time your component gets updated/rendered*. This would explain the exponential amount of triggers. The `useEffect` hook can be quite unintuitive at first, so I recommend reading up on it a bit. The docs do quite a good job at explaining the concept. I also found [this article by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) immensely helpful when I first started using effects.
2. The way you call your `setState` function will always cause your component to update, no matter whether the current state already matches your media query, because you pass it a new object with every update. Unlike the `setState` method of class based components  (which compares object key/values iirc), the hook version only checks for [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) when determining whether an update should trigger a re-render. An example:

```
{ foo: 'bar' } === { foo: 'bar' } // Always returns false. Try it in your console.
```

To prevent that from happening, you could set up a state hook that really only tracks the match result and derive your flags from it. Booleans work just fine with reference equality:

```
const [doesMatch, setDoesMatch] = useState(false)
```

So to put it all together:

```js
const mediaQuery = '(max-width: 960px)';
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery);


const MyComponent = () => 
   const [match, updateMatch] = useState(false)
   useEffect(() => {
      const handleChange = (event) => {
          updateMatch(event.matches)
      } 
      mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
      return () => {
         // This is called the cleanup phase aka beforeUnmount
         mediaQueryList.removeEventListener('change', handleChange)   
      }
   }, []) // Only do this once, aka hook-ish way of saying didMount
   
   const desktopNavActivated = !match

   // ...
   // Further process your match result and return JSX or whatever
}
```

Again, I would really advise you to go over the React docs and some articles when you find the time. Hooks are awesome, but without understanding the underlying concepts they can become very frustrating to work with rather quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the learning resources and the solution! I edited a bit to fit my needs, but this worked like a charm. Definitely going to brush on on useEffect more